# Is it possible in git to push commits depending on the user?

Tags: git, github

I would like to know if it's possible to push content that was last committed by a certain user.

For example if I have 3 users ( A, B, C) and I want just to push the content committed by one of them (e.g A), how would that be? Is it possible?

Thanks for your time!

PS: I want to do this because we're working with branches and happens that we can only have one branch at once to the test server so it's a big deal to be all time changing branches and wait to someone finish to see how's his branch going and so.. Anyone maybe thinks there's a better approach?

I think that there's possible a better approach but for now with just merging branches and later committing what I've done or another coworker (to the production server) I think it's fine

Comment: You could, but it isn't easy, produces a big complicated mess, and is totally unnecessary. Instead, could you describe that workflow in more detail? That sounds like the real problem. It sounds like you're using branches in a very inefficient manner, perhaps you're used to centralized version control like SVN. There are much better Git workflows.

Comment: We have two servers a one were we have our website and all the features that are being tested or created and then we have the client one were we just have the finished features to the client be able to work with the website and so. In the github we have for each worker one branch and each one of us is implementing a feature.